# Detect Beats From iPhone Microphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I was wondering how does this app [RoboStrobe](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/robostrobe-free/id403675608?mt=8) detect the beats. I'm using "AVAudioRecorder" to listen to the Mic and get the sound level meter, but I don't know the proper way to calculate the level and beats and fire my method.

Here is what I do now:

Call The Update Method:

```
levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.05 target: self selector: @selector(levelTimerCallback:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
```

And My Update Method

```
-(void)update
{
[recorder updateMeters];


const double ALPHA = 0.05;
double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;

double scale = lowPassResults * 5;
NSLog(@"Result = %f",scale);
if (scale>4.5) {
    [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:1.0];
    NSLog(@"HEAVY Scale = %f",scale);
    [self turnTorchOn:YES];
    [self performSelector:@selector(off) withObject:Nil afterDelay:0.4];
}

else
{
    [self turnTorchOn:NO];
    [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:0.1];
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Beat detection requires non-trivial audio processing (comb filter, onset detection etc.). You'll want to use a library for it. Possible candidates are:

- [aubio](http://aubio.org/)
- [vamp](http://www.vamp-plugins.org/index.html)
- [Sound Touch Audio Processing Library](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/)

But there are many more out there. And there are many related questions on StackOverflow.